# Como sinalizar respostas em inglês?

Tags: debate, respostas, sinalização

Veja essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249299/41056). Está em inglês, então fui sinalizar. Nas opções de sinalização não há alternativa para tal. Seria um caso para chamar intervenção dos moderadores?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu acho muito melhor comentar pro autor e, se for possível, editá-la.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a resposta não é longa a primeira opção é a tradução. Pode até jogar o link dela no chat caso alguém tenha disponibilidade de fazer ajustes caso tenha usado algum tradutor. Também deixe um comentário para o autor sobre o idioma do site e que ele pode usar um tradutor :).

Quando não tiver nenhuma outra alternativa pode marcar ela como "não é um resposta" ou flag dos moderadores na descrição deixe "resposta em inglês"